# CDI and Spring hand in hand

Tags: spring, cdi

Is there any chance that CDI and spring dependency injection could co-exist. The problem started when I tried using JpaRepository interface.

I cannot remove beans.xml as it breaks a common jar implementation which uses CDI. I tried @Vetoed but it then fails to autowire my JpaRepository interface in a service class. Does it mean that @Vetoed prevents the bean from being managed by spring also?

I am looking for an idea so that i could use CDI to manage some beans and spring to manage the rest.

Comment: create spring managed wrappers that programatically load cdi beans?

Comment: It worked for me when I excluded the package in beans.xml. But not sure why @Vetoed didnt work.